# Add image and text to element with jQuerys HTML?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add both an image and some text to an element with jQuerys HTML, but it's not working!? Can I do it in some other way?

```
var saveTime = "Text sparad: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
$("#status").html("<img src='grafik/bullet_disk.png' />" + saveTime);
```

Comment: The code you posted is correct. Either `h`, `m` or `s` are not defined or you not running the code when `#status` is available.

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with id 'status'? Did you mean '.png'?

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not working* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check

```
/bullet_disk.pnp
```

must be

```
/bullet_disk.png
```

And always add `alt=""` (even empty) to an img element in order to pass validation :)